# crontab not working with celery multi start

Tags: django, celery, celery-task

I am trying to get Celery work for awhile now. All my crontabs works just fine when I test it synchronously

```
sudo celery -A testdjango worker --loglevel=DEBUG --beat
```

but when I do

```
celery multi start -A testdjango w1 -l info
```

none of my crontabs work. I am not sure why

Note: I tried other schedule intervals as well like with `time delta` The same thing happens with that as well.

So I am fairly certain this is not a crontab thing but somehow related to the way I am starting celery multi.

Also, the worker turns on just fine since I can see it in [Celery Flower](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but no tasks get executed.

Comment: What does your log file look like? The problem is probably stored there.
If you don't have one you can create the folder with "mkdir -p /var/log/celery"
and then call celery multi start with the following parameter
"--logfile=/var/log/celery/%n.pid"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the answer is pretty straightforward

Since periodic tasks need [Beat](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler) just add --beat with the command.

something like this

```
celery multi start -A testdjango w1 --beat -l info
```

Comment: I've been searching this argument since forever.. and here you go, the only answer on the whole web!

Comment: @holms yeah it took me awhile as well

Comment: maybe you know, how to specify couple of workers (by name) with queues?

Comment: if I have multiple queues, this will repeat the task for each queue

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively instead of running Beat inside your worker process (which the docs for 3.1.18 say is not recommended) you can run it dedicated in the background with

```
celery beat -A testdjango --pidfile=/blah/beat.pid --detach
```

Be sure to save the pidfile somewhere so you can also kill the process later.